# Android Studio Gradle Version 5.1.1 Problem

Tags: android, gradle

I have a simple Android app developed in Android studio. When I built it with Gradle 4.10.1, there was no warning or error. After I updated Gradle to Version 5.1.1, I got the following warning:

Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
Changing the value for a property with a final value has been deprecated. This will fail with an error in Gradle 6.0.

What do I need to do to remove this warning? Can anybody help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -2):

In gradle-wrapper.properties(File Name) change URL of distributionUrl to the following:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Comment: Mohit, your suggestion will change my Gradle version to 4.6. I mentioned in my question that there was no build error with Gradle version 4.10. I think your suggestion would result in an error free build but I would like to use the latest Gradle.

Comment: Untill you don't find the solution. You can use my answer and you are good to go. Updating latest gradle always messes up the whole project.